# Casting int to byte after xoring

Tags: c#, exception, casting

I'm having a problem casting a int bigger than 255 into a byte. The problem is that I have two programs executing the same code. On one I get exceptions and in the other I don't, even with the compile settings being the same. 
The code is this:

```
   private static byte[] MixRound(byte[] input, Random RNG, int seed)
    {
        bool[] cellMap = new bool[input.Length];
        byte[] output = new byte[input.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            int value = input[NewLocation(cellMap, RNG)];
            int xor = seed * (i + seed);
            int xorValue = value ^ xor;
            output[i] = (byte)(xorValue);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

The line where the exception is thrown is this:

```
 output[i] = (byte)(xorValue);
```

With a "System.OverflowException", saying that "the arithmetic opeation caused an overflow".

I don't think it's normal for two diferent projects with the same code on the same computer.

Comment: Do you have checked arithmetic turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control integer overflow with `checked` and `unchecked` keywords:

```
  // Throw exception
  checked {
    output[i] = (byte)(xorValue);
  }
```

And

```
  // Do not throw exception
  unchecked {
    output[i] = (byte)(xorValue);
  }
```